# Does hyperledger composer support composite keys?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

In hyperledger composer, can an asset be identified by a composite key, and is it possible to get the assets by a partial key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, identifiers for resources in Composer are simple strings. You can use Composer queries to retrieve resources by content.